# How to send error message with restfulAPI using SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I have server which is built using SpringBoot and restful api's. It is simple CRUD application.

I am trying to check if email already exists while adding a new user.

I am not sure how to send error messages over rest api. I have tried like this:

**UserController.java**

```java
  //POST method for adding one user
    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        User existingUser = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if(existingUser != null){
            throw new UserAlreadyExistException("User with this email already exists");
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.saveUser(user), HttpStatus.OK) ;
    }
```

**UserAlreadyExistException.java**

```java
public class UserAlreadyExistException extends RuntimeException{

    public UserAlreadyExistException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

When I test it with Postman I get `Error: 500 Internal Server Error`

And in `InteliJ` I have this exception thrown:

> com.example.library.UserAlreadyExistException: User with this email
> already exists

Is this a correct way to do it or what is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler`.  The way such exceptions are handled is:

1. Create a global exception handler and annotate with `@ControllerAdvice`
2. Catch your exception using `@ExceptionHandler` in one of the methods specific to a certain exception.

So, adding below code will catch the exception and return custom response.

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAuthenticationException(UserAlreadyExistException e) {
        // do what you want with e
        return new ResponseEntity<>("User already exists", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```